# keytool error :Alias ​​<andoiddebugkey> does not exist

Tags: android, google-maps, md5

I get an error when I write this command in the console

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin> keytool-list-alias-andoiddebugkey keystore C:\Users\AbuHamza\android\debug.keystore-storepass android-keypass androi. d
```

error

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias ​​<andoiddebugkey> does not exist
```

Comment: you have typo mistake, it's `androiddebugkey`, you missed the `r` in `android`.

Comment: Solution
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\keytool" -V -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\AbuHamza\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android